# How to set field value as the result of a calculation

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that has a field whose value is from a php calculation. The Calculation is just basic arithmetic involving purely whole numbers. But there is a scenario where the value will be zero. So the form assumes that that filed has been left empty.

How can i go round that ? 
Here is a sample of code.

```
if ( 
    isset($_POST['input1']) &&
    isset($_POST['input2']) &&
    isset($_POST['ans'])
    )
{   
    // CHECKING IF ANY OF THE FIELDS WERE LEFT EMPTY
    $input1 = $_POST['input1'];
    $input2 = $_POST['input2'];
    $ans = ($input1)-($input2);
    $ans_set = 0;

    if ($ans === $ans_set ) {
        # code...
        //echo "Same";
        $ans = '0';
    } else {
        # code...
        //echo "Different";
        echo "Check data types";
    }


    if ( 
        !empty($input1) &&
        !empty($input2) &&
        !empty($ans) 
         )
    {   
        $query = "INSERT INTO formaths VALUES ( 'NUll', NOW(),
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($input1)."',
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($input2)."',
                        '".mysql_real_escape_string($ans)."' )";

        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
                    if ( $query_run )
                    {
                        //header("Location:". __DIR__."../registration_success.php");
                        echo "<p class='echo'>Data entry was successful.</p>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<p class='echo'>It seems that we couldn't save that at this time.</p>";
                    }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p class='echo'>Please make sure all fields are filled and are correct.<br/>You must fill in the area field last!</p>";
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="formaths.php" method="POST">
        <input name="input1" type="text" autofocus/>
        <input name="input2" type="text"/>
        <input name="ans" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($ans)) { echo $ans; }?>" readonly />

        <input type="submit" value="DO IT" />
    </form>
    enter code here

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any code, but i assume `intval()` or `floatval()` will help you.

Comment: Your second to last sentence doesn't make sense. Are you saying you want the form to see the field as empty when the calculation is zero?

Comment: If you still want to `INSERT` when the answer value is `0` you should check only `input1` and `input2` for being empty.